# PointerEvents: Detect touching "through" an element

Tags: javascript, android, dom, smartphone, pointer-events

Using pointer events, I can't find the right event to trigger for finger-based touches on smartphones (tested with Chrome Android and Chrome Devtools with mobile emulation).

What I need: A "hover" event if you touch action *passes through* an element while holding the finger down moving over the screen.

That is, put your finger down outside the element, move through it, and move finger up only after completely passing through the element.

I attached a code snipped to clearify: I don't need events for the blue elements, I would only need respective "in/out" events for the red element in the snippet. The sample JS code will fire for the mouse, but on mobile it does not trigger any console.infos.

```js
var elem = document.querySelector(".element");

elem.addEventListener("pointerover", function() {
    console.clear();
    console.info("pointerover triggered");
});
elem.addEventListener("pointerenter", function() {
    console.clear();
    console.info("pointerenter triggered");
});
elem.addEventListener("pointerleave", function() {
    console.clear();
    console.info("pointerleave triggered");
});
```

```css
.outer {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 3px solid grey;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: white;
    text-align:center;
    touch-action: none;
    
}

.start {
   position: relative;
   top:0px;
   left:0px;
   width: 100px;
   height: 20px;
   background-color: blue;
}

.element {
   position: relative;
   top: 20px;
   left: 0px;
   width: 100px;
   height: 20px;
   background-color: red;
}

.end {
   position: relative;
   top: 40px;
   right: 0;
   width: 100px;
   height: 20px;
   background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="start">Start touch here</div>
    <div class="element">Move over here</div>
    <div class="end">End touch here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think those events work on mobile at all. Try with `pointermove`

Comment: Neither `pointermove` nor `pointerover` will be fired when start AND end of the touch is outside the red element.

Comment: `pointerover` doesn't work on mobile either. You will have to manually implement such logic, I'm afraid.

Comment: I hope that I understand you correctly because in your question we could misinterpret the task – it is relatively difficalt to understand the task without images. After a lot of shaman dances with a tambourine (a lot of time) I found two solutions for you.

Comment: @Bharata I think thats unfair to claim, I provided a running snippet that works on dekstop with the mouse but not on a smartphone. What I asked for is how to get that working on a smartphone, so I think its pretty clear what my question is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hope that I understand you correctly. I wrote and tested for you two different solutions: pointerevents and touch events. In each move event from this events you can detect the current element with the function **[`document.elementFromPoint()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementFromPoint)**.

**Solution with pointerevents**

Maybe you can use pointerevents – they work in Chrome Devtools with mobile emulation, but not work on **my** Android device (*I think my device is too old*). Or maybe you can use it with Pointer Events Polyfill. The Browser compatibility for pointerevents you can see **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/pointermove#Browser_compatibility)**.

```js
var elementFromPoint,
    isFingerDown = false,
    isThroughElemMoved = false,
    elem = document.querySelector('.element'),
    output = document.querySelector('#output');

document.addEventListener('pointerdown', function(e)
{
    if(elem != e.target)
    {
        isFingerDown = true;
        output.innerHTML = 'pointer-START';
    }
});

document.addEventListener('pointermove', function(e)
{
    elementFromPoint = document.elementFromPoint(e.pageX - window.pageXOffset, e.pageY - window.pageYOffset);

    if(elem == elementFromPoint)
    {
        isThroughElemMoved = true;
        output.innerHTML = 'pointer-MOVE';
    }
});

document.addEventListener('pointerup', function(e)
{
    if(isFingerDown && isThroughElemMoved && elem != elementFromPoint)
        output.innerHTML = 'It is done!';

    isFingerDown = isThroughElemMoved = false;
});
```

```css
.outer
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 3px solid grey;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    /*touch-action: none*/
}
.outer div{position: relative; left: 0; height: 20px}
.start{top: 0; background: blue}
.element{top: 20px; background: red}
.end{top: 40px; background: blue}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="start">Start touch here</div>
    <div class="element">Move over here</div>
    <div class="end">End touch here</div>
</div>
<br><br>
<div id="output">info</div>
```

**Solution with touch events**

But you can use **[touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events)** too. Unfortunatelly, the events `touchenter` and `touchleave` were deleted from the specification and because of them we have to write a workaround using `document.elementFromPoint()` too.

The following snippet works only in the mobile emulation (tested with Chrome Devtools) or  on devices which support touch events (tested with Android).

```js
var elementFromPoint,
    isFingerDown = false,
    isThroughElemMoved = false,
    elem = document.querySelector('.element'),
    output = document.querySelector('#output');

document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e)
{
    if(elem != e.target)
    {
        isFingerDown = true;
        output.innerHTML = 'touch-START';
    }
});

document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e)
{
    var touch = e.touches[0];
    
    elementFromPoint = document.elementFromPoint(touch.pageX - window.pageXOffset, touch.pageY - window.pageYOffset);

    if(elem == elementFromPoint)
    {
        isThroughElemMoved = true;
        output.innerHTML = 'touch-MOVE';
    }
});

document.addEventListener('touchend', function(e)
{
    if(isFingerDown && isThroughElemMoved && elem != elementFromPoint)
        output.innerHTML = 'It is done!';

    isFingerDown = isThroughElemMoved = false;
});
```

```css
.outer
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 3px solid grey;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    /*touch-action: none*/
}
.outer div{position: relative; left: 0; height: 20px}
.start{top: 0; background: blue}
.element{top: 20px; background: red}
.end{top: 40px; background: blue}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="start">Start touch here</div>
    <div class="element">Move over here</div>
    <div class="end">End touch here</div>
</div>
<br><br>
<div id="output">info</div>
```

**Maybe the following links can help you:**

- **[Get element from point when you have overlapping elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22428553)**
- **[How to find out the actual event.target of touchmove javascript
  event?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19511757)**

Comment: Accept your solution for `elementFromPoint()`. This is vastly superior to bounding box hit tests, as it works for any SVG shape/path elements, and also for SVG lines which do not have a fill but only a stroke property.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<script>
    var startElem = document.querySelector(".start");
    var endElem = document.querySelector(".end");
    var elem = document.querySelector(".element");

    var started = false;
    var passedThroughStart = false;
    var passedThroughEnd = false;
    var ended = false;

    startElem.addEventListener("pointerdown", function(e){
        started = true;
    });

    window.addEventListener("pointermove", function(e) {
        var x = e.clientX;
        var y = e.clientY;
        var bounds = elem.getBoundingClientRect();

        if( !passedThroughStart &&
            x > bounds.left && x < bounds.left + bounds.width &&
            y > bounds.top && y < bounds.top + bounds.height
        ){
            passedThroughStart = true;
        }

        if( passedThroughStart && !passedThroughEnd &&
            x > bounds.left && x < bounds.left + bounds.width &&
            y > bounds.top + bounds.height
        ){
            passedThroughEnd = true;
        }
    })

    window.addEventListener("pointerup", function(e) {
        var x = e.clientX;
        var y = e.clientY;
        var bounds = endElem.getBoundingClientRect();

        ended = ( x > bounds.left && x < bounds.left + bounds.width && y > bounds.top && y < bounds.top + bounds.height)

        if( started && passedThroughStart && passedThroughEnd && ended ){
            console.log("Hooray!");
        }

        started = false;
        passedThroughStart = false;
        passedThroughEnd = false;
        ended = false;
    });
</script>
```

Alternatively use `pointerenter` and `pointerleave` rather than `pointermove`

```
elem.addEventListener('pointenter', function(e) {
    passedThroughStart = true;
}
elem.addEventListener('pointleave', function(e) {
    passedThroughEnd = true;
}
```

Comment: I don't think `touchenter / touchleave` exist. Also, for what its worth, this guy recommends trying to limit scope of touch handler so it doesn't wreck havoc with scrolling: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touchandmouse/ -- but good call on trying out touch events!

Comment: I specifically want pointerevents, but I also think my specific code example does not work with touch events. Feel free to provider a working example

Comment: I've updated but I am working on a more concise answer

Comment: Ok... I think I have it working now ;) just updated the answer again. I have only tested this on chrome using the device mode

Comment: I had hoped to avoid manual bounding box hit tests, but I seems there is no way around it. Works for rectangular shapes and circles, but gets awfully complex for non regular elements (i use SVGs...)

Comment: It also appears that pointer events are not fully supported on mobile: https://caniuse.com/#search=pointerover

Comment: @ShawnNorthrop but there are polyfills for that

Comment: True... If you use the polyfils then you can probably utilize the above code but insted of `window.addEventListener("pointermove.."` you can use `elem.addEventListener("pointerenter...` and `elem.addEventListener("pointerout...` to set the `passedThroughStart/End` values