# Capturing mouse moves on an svg rect while allowing the event to percolate downward as well

Tags: html, svg, dom

If I have the following svg:

```html
<svg>
  <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="10" fill="rgb(0,0,0)" />
  <circle cx="80" cy="80" r="10" fill="rgb(0,0,0)" />
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0.0)" />
</svg>
```

and if I add an `onmousemove` listener to all three objects, only the transparent rectangle in front will pick up the mouse move. Assuming the mouse is over one of the circles, is there a way to trigger `onmousemove` on the front rect *and* the circle underneath. IIRC, `pointer-events:none` can be used to ignore the mouse event on the upper rect, but this is not what I'm looking for - I'm looking for `onmousemove` to be called on *both* objects.

Thanks in advance for any tips!

Comment: Please take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55906822/how-to-make-an-hover-effect-on-two-overlapping-shapes-in-svg/55909387#55909387

Comment: Thanks for that! I wound up redesigning my app in a more idiomatically dom-y way to avoid this problem.