# How to get id from document.elementFromPoint with same x coordinates in javascript? I want all div id's like that

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, reactjs

I have two div with same x position. And i am trying to do that getting id of both divs from document.elementFromPoint(). Here is the problem that only id recieved of a div.

```js
var elem = document.elementFromPoint(50, 50);
var elem2 = document.elementFromPoint(50, 250);
console.log(elem.id, elem2.id);
```

```css
#box1,
#box2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: greenyellow;
}

#box1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}

#box2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1"></div>
<div id="box2"></div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get element from point when you have overlapping elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22428484/get-element-from-point-when-you-have-overlapping-elements)

Comment: _"I have two div with same x position"_ - That's not the case (`left: 50px`, `left: 150px`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty close, but if you check out the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementFromPoint), your parameters are switched round.

```
document.elementFromPoint(x, y)
```

Where `x` is `left`, `y` is `top`.

```js
var elem = document.elementFromPoint(50, 50);
var elem2 = document.elementFromPoint(150, 50);
console.log(elem.id, elem2.id);
```

```css
#box1,
#box2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: greenyellow;
}

#box1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}

#box2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1"></div>
<div id="box2"></div>
```