# how to move a image with arrow keys and get id of behind div in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have done successfully moved a image with arrow keys but now i want getting id behind the moved image. And here i want all div id when image overlap.

> html

```
<div id="box2"></div>
<div id="box3"></div>
<div id="box4"></div>
<div id="box5"></div>
<img id="image" src="http://placekitten.com/69/69" style="position:absolute;left:0; top:0; z-index: 1;" height="15" width="15">
```

> css

```
body{background:yellow;}
#box2, 
#box3, 
#box4, 
#box5 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: greenyellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  z-index: 2 
}

#box3 {
  top: 150px;
  left: 150px; 
}

#box4 {
  top: 50px;
  left: 250px;
}
```

> Please check demostration link

https://jsfiddle.net/36y0ztn9/1/

Comment: Your image is not moving . please provide the full working code .

Comment: You should probably use [`getBoundingClientRect()` Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getboundingclientrect.asp) to get the positions of the boxes first and then when the image is moved, calculate the position of the image to check if it is inside one of the boxes.

Comment: @PushprajsinhChudasama Please check link https://jsfiddle.net/p0nkfdwr/3/

Comment: @jaysurya I have already used that method thats method does not work me

Comment: @PraveenKumar Why didn't it work? You might need to use it this way - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52477551/7314900. add the window scroll position to the values obtained by `getBoundingClientRect()` method.

Comment: @jaysurya I want different result Please check demo link https://jsfiddle.net/p0nkfdwr/3/. here i want that div id which overlaped by image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up to my comments above,

`document.elementFromPoint` only gets the top most element - [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementFromPoint), which here is the image itself, so use a work around like setting `display:none` or `pointer-events:none` to the image to make the box as the top most elem and get the box Id. Then reset the value back.

Check this working fiddle, where I made some modifications to yours : https://jsfiddle.net/y6xsnc8h/1

Also Check this answer for a reusable function : https://stackoverflow.com/a/22428553/7314900

Answer (score 0):

for getting id you can use`document.querySelector('#idname) or document.getElementById('idname')` in your JavaScript file.